# biblatex: separator for citing multiple sources, some of them with page, some not

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using biblatex for my references.

Normally, if I use `\cite{source1, source2, source3}`, I get a citation like

```
[3, 45, 98]
```

If I now want to give a page number for one of them, it looks confusing imho, as I should get (did not try it out up to now, honestly)

```
[3, 45, 78, p. 23f, 98]
```

So imho it would make sense to change one of the separator from a comma to e. g. a semicolon like:

```
[3; 45; 78, p. 23f; 98]
```

**Question 1:** Does that make sense, or are there other conventions for citing sources with and without page numbers together?

(Up to now I collected the citations without page number in one `cite` command and added singular `\cite[][p. xy]{}` commands for those with page numbers., so I'd get:

```
 [3, 45, 98][78, p. 23f]
```

)

the `\cites[]{}[]{}[]{}` could also do that, but it also uses the same separators for entries and postnotes.

**Question 2:** How could I change the separator globally for those number-citations from comma to semicolon in biblatex?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It makes sense indeed; the documentation of **biblatex** says that the default action of `\multicitedelim` is to add a semicolon followed by a space, but it appears not to be so. Write

```
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}
```

in your preamble, after having loaded **biblatex**.

Comment: The documentation is imprecise: `\multicitedelim` is defined as `\addsemicolon\space` in `biblatex.def`, but this is changed to `\addcomma\space` in the `numeric` citation style (which is `biblatex`s default style).