# Multiple references with \footfullcite

Tags: biblatex

I use `\footfullcite{}` to include the complete reference in footnotes on the same page. I now have the problem that I want to cite multiple references. Either I would like them to be separated by a semicolon in the footnote so that

```
Check.\footfullcite{Book1, Book2}
```

would give the following output

> Check.[1]
>
> [1] A. Author, Alpha, 2001; B. Buthor, Bravo, 2002.

or, ideally, I want it to look like this

> Check.[1-2]
>
> [1] A. Author, Alpha, 2001.
>
> [2] B. Buthor, Bravo, 2002.

Is this possible by using \footfullcite?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew, safeinputenc]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@misc{Book1,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{Book2,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Check.\footfullcite{Book1}
Check.\footfullcite{Book1, Book2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding

```
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}
```

to your preamble, a semicolons is placed between multiple items. Found this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29084/biblatex-separator-for-citing-multiple-sources-some-of-them-with-page-some-no).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the above solution by @hnina didn't work. So as an instant solution, I did it in the following way-

```
\footfullcite{abc}$^{,\hspace{2pt}}$\footfullcite{xyz}
```